# Distance metric for sparse matrix with imbalanced data

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, distance-functions

I am trying to find similar movies in a dataset where each movie has zero to five genres. (I also have more dimensions but those are not relevant to the question.)

For this I'm trying to use nearest neighbors. The data is transformed into a matrix of approximately 100 columns using either MultiLabelClassifier or TF-IDF.

The problem I'm having is that the distance metrics I have found/tried all have a problem with this kind of data, where missing data gets a lower distance than non-matching data. This creates a heavy bias against the lower quality data in the dataset.

Some example data to illustrate the issue:

|  | genres |
| --- | --- |
| movie1 | ['action','thriller','crime'] |
| movie2 | ['drama','romance'] |
| movie3 | ['action'] |
| movie4 | [] |

|  | genre_action | genre_drama | genre_thriller | genre_romance | genre_crime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| movie1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| movie2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| movie3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| movie4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Using the manhattan distance this results in the following distances:

|  | movie1 | movie2 | movie3 | movie4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| movie1 | 0 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| movie2 | 5 | 0 | 3 | 2 |
| movie3 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| movie4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

Here I want movie1 - movie2 to have the same distance as movie3 - movie4. Or expressed differently, I want the distance `['action'] - ['romance']` to be equal to the distance `['action'] - []`. It would also be useful if the distance between `[] - []` was large.

I think of it as something like the inverse of the size of the intersection. The closest I have found is the jaccard distance but as it also uses the union it doesn't quite do what I need.

Is there a distance metric that has these properties or am I approaching the problem from the wrong direction?

Comment: Maybe `XOR/AND`?